# Represent a DNF formula as a multivariate linear formula?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Lets say I have the following DNF: (x or y) and (z or i) / $(x\lor y)\land(z\lor i)$
How do I convert that into a polynomial form?

Answer (score 1):

Usually one represents disjunction by addition and conjunction by multiplication, so a suitable polynomial would be $(x + y) \cdot (z + w)$ (I renamed $i$ to $w$ here as to not create confusion w.r.t. the imaginary unit).
Note that plugging in $0$ or $1$ depending on the desired truth values yields 0 precisely if the original formula would evaluate to false while any value greater than zero indicates that such an assignment would satisfy the formula.

You mention *linear* in your title, however I do not think that there is a sensible way to represent propositional formulas by linear functions.